# can one say "he is my biggest example"?

Tags: collocation

can one say "he is my biggest example" (if one wants to say someone serves as a shining/inspiring/great example for oneself)? Or in other words does example collocate with big(gest)? (Non-native teacher of English asking, since a pupil wrote it and it sounds a bit odd to me)

Comment: "he is my foremost example"

Comment: that might not be strictly wrong but why would you want to say anything that way when you could so much more simply use "… my best example"?

Either way, why did you post no research, please?

Comment: Of course I first tried to find the answer to this question on the web without having to bother people on this forum. The results of my 'research' were not conclusive, though. I'm a non-native teacher of English, and I try to be as just as possible to my pupils and not underline things just because they sound odd to me. However I can't spend an hour of research on every single case I am not quite sure about. Am I wrong in assuming that this forum also has the purpose of helping people like me with those kind of questions?

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong but sounds odd since I've never heard such a usage. I'd say "he is my greatest example" or just "he is my example" - or better yet, "my greatest influence".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say "someone serves as a shining/inspiring example for oneself", you can say, "he is my biggest **role model**".

"Example" is not normally used to describe a person to be emulated.

You can say, "set a good example" for another person, meaning "to show somebody something to follow". In this case, "example" refers to an act that emulates another act (not one that emulates a person).